# How to ensure Powershell script continues to run independently of logged-in user

Tags: powershell

I have a small piece of Powershell code that basically uploads some files on a constant base via azcopy to Azure in Windows. The script is executed when the PC turns on and someone is logged in. (autostart). Sometimes a person logs the current user out and logs in with their own credential.

How can I ensure that this script runs all the time regardless of which person is logged in?
The script accesses a local network path and copys all files to Azure.
Any ideas?

Comment: One option is to define a scheduled task that runs at system startup and therefore runs independently of whether a user is logged on or who. The user identity for that task will need to have access to the network path of interest. Note that the task will invariably run _invisibly_.

Comment: Would it be possible to register a windows service that always runs? And the service basically executes powershell script?

Comment: technically you could make your own service even just to do this in c# or something, but it would be a bit overkill, when a system scheduled task would do?